# Defining Variables In A Namespace

Tags: c++

We can define free floating variables in a namespace

```
namespace foo {
    int x;
}
```

We can assign its value

```
namespace foo {
    int x;

    void bar() {
        x = 4;
    }
}
```

We could also assign the value during declaration

```
namespace foo {
    int x = 4;
}
```

Is there anything inherently wrong with doing these things inside of a namespace? Things to be aware of that could potentially happen differently from if we were to do all these things inside of a class instead?

Comment: You can't do `Integers.reserve(100);` at namespace scope

Comment: "_Slightly more complex things could be done_" But, you [can't do those](https://wandbox.org/permlink/707buQBDWUtbyZPw)..

Comment: You examples are the norm.

Comment: Namespaces are "just" ways to organise your global variables (and functions and classes). Nothing is really different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The C++ is valid, but it's bad practice to use global variables.** 
There's nothing in the language that prevents you from doing this, but in general, it's a good idea to avoid using global variables. Global constants (like Pi) are fine, but using global variables can:

- Make code harder to understand;
- Make it harder to debug;
- Make it harder to change when you revisit the code a month or two in the future.

**Why is this true?** Functions that use or modify global variables can be difficult to understand. If a function relies on global variables, you need to configure those globals properly before calling the function, and you need to make sure that other functions won't break if they're called after that function.

All of this is especially true if you decide to make it multithreaded later. This is because global variables are shared between threads, and as a result if multiple threads are changing a global variable, it leads to race conditions that can break code.

Here's a good article that explains this in greater depth! https://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad

Comment: Are there any performance implications from using these global namespace variables? I feel like defining variables like this in the context of someone designing a library could be acceptable, especially when the end-user of such a library would never directly access these variables?